# Passing a variable value to a variable in a script function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to pass the value of a variable in JavaScript file to a variable in a script function which is written on top of the HTML file.

I wrote it like this:

*myjsfile.js*:

```
var abc = "10";
```

*HTML file*:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

var test = document.createElement('script'); test.type = 'text/javascript'; test.async = true;

test.src = 'testquery.js';

var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);

alert(abc);
})();

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting the output. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Basically I am trying to create a jquery plugin just like Google analytics.

Answer (score 2):

The script has to load first, try using `onload`

```
test.onload=function(){alert(abc);}
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked. can i know how to display an image using the external javascript file. That is instead of variable i want to display image which is called from jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(abc);
    </script>
 </head>
 <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: test.onload=function(){alert(abc);} code worked for me.... But how to display image which is stored in external jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(function() {

    var test = document.createElement('script');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(test);
    test.type = 'text/javascript';
    test.src = 'testquery.js';

    test.onload = function () {
        alert(abc);
    }

})();​
```

well.. the onload has already been told but you should at least switch your way of appending it to the head.